# How to enable navigation from JSF page to a specific Angular page?

Tags: angular, jsf

I'm working on a project that the client is written at JSF and the backend at Java EE running on Wildfly.
The team is considering moving to Angular.
The approach is to write new pages at Angular and slowly replace old JSF pages.

How to enable navigation from JSF page to a specific Angular page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating from JSF to AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192710/migrating-from-jsf-to-angularjs)

Comment: Then the question is sort of off-topic for stackoverflow and more fore software engineering: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JasperdeVries it's not a duplicate...

Comment: Please don't modify your question into something completely new. Instead, please create a new one.

Comment: I'm confused, should I delete this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if writing new pages at Angular and running them alongside
>   the current JSF client under the same hood make sense, if so, how
>   would you do that?

As long as your backend services are constructed of managed beans of some sort (cdi, jsf etc), all the ways to it goes through some hacky paths besides it can also take much more effort than you expect.

If you had a restfull service at the backend *"writing new pages at Angular and running them alongside the current JSF client under the same hood"* would make sense and all it takes would be some redirection configurations at the jsf side for specific pages to serve your angular application or using hash-location strategy.
Implementing such a case is not that complicated.
Steps basically would be like this:

- Build your angular project with the same context-path as your
  jsf context-path plus a name for your angular folder, like this:

  ng build --prod --base-href "/myjsfapp/angular/" --deploy-url "/myjsfapp/angular/"
- Create a folder named angular inside your jsf webapp folder and place your angular distrubution files inside it.

After having done the steps above, your angular application will be served under /context-path/angular/index.html path.

Accessing the angular pages however will require more attention. Because an angular application is about one page (index.html) all the pages are actually logical pages served at runtime inside the same index.html. That's why when you try to access one of your pages, lets say users page, inside your angular application your server will kick in and search for a physicall /users.html page and return an http 404. To handle this you can set redirection rules or pick the easiest way that is hash-location strategy. Using hash-location strategy in your angular application is done easily by adding {useHash:true} configuration in forRoot call. (If you go with this strategy this should be the first step to do)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  ...
})
```

With hash-location strategy your angular pages will be accessible with hashed urls.
For example, http://localhost:8080/myjsfapp/angular/index.html#users

Comment: Most of the business tier is exposed via REST, I understand it will require to add new APIs. How would you do the redirection configurations? What will happen if the user logged in via the JSF client and then you redirect him to the Angular client?

Comment: I'm editing my answer with more information.

Comment: The information is really good, will try this Monday!
The last piece that I'm missing is, how will you handle the login?

Comment: @spaykit could you detail your point about login?

Comment: You login from the JSF client, then you are redirected to some Angular page, the Angular client doesn't know who you are, so the next REST call will require credentials or even keep navigating inside the Angular app will require credentials.

Comment: Did you get my point? @talhature